# How to run sudo gedit without connection refusal?

Tags: centos, gedit, ssh-config

I'm installing and configuring the ssh in CentOs 8 with a virtual box machine.

I installed both libraries with following command:

```
sudo yum install openssh-server openssh-clients
```

Then I started the service with:

```
sudo systemctl enable sshd
sudo systemctl start sshd
sudo systemctl status sshd
```

And it's running normally.

When I try to edit the sshd_config file with the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

I get the following error:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:5680): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:59:00.071: cannot open display: :0
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You're likely running Xwindows under your account, but are trying to open the gedit session as root with the ```sudo``` command.  Try ```xhost +127.0.0.1``` to allow any user from the local host to access the display, then try the command again.

Comment: Welcome! It looks to me like you are not allowed to connect to the display because you use sudo. You can test whether using sudo gedit for other files in /etc also gets you this effect. If that's the case, the problem might be related to your display manager, wayland? with xorg it might work.

Comment: When I ran `sudo gedit /etc/sudoers` I got the same error.

Comment: Tried `xhost +127.0.0.1` with no success.

Comment: try ```xhost local:``` instead

Comment: please specify the question: is it: how can i run sudo gedit without connection refusal?

Comment: see also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-WVc9HGCfI

Comment: @Fubar, thanks! Just post your answer bellow to get a reputation point. It did work for me! Could you explain why does it solve my problem? I'm still learning Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely running Xwindows under your account, but are trying to open the gedit session as root with the sudo command. Try `xhost local:` to allow any user from the local host to access the display, then try the command again.  If that works, you can refine it more to just allow root to access the display with `xhost +SI:localuser:root`

Answer (score 2):

Please try to added switch `-E` after `sudo` command:

```
sudo -E gedit /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of opening gedit from the shell, I suggest you use a terminal editor, like [vi](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/UnixAndC/Editors/ViIntro.html).

```
sudo vi /path/to/file
```

Comment: I still have to use `gedit`